# Unable to insert contact record on button click using lwc and apex controller

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, imperativeapex

Button is created in quick action bar on an account record.

```
HTML FILE  

<template>
    <lightning-card title="New contact" icon-name="standard:contact">
        <div class="slds-p-around_x-small">
            <lightning-input type="text" label="First name" value={rec.FNAME} onchange={handlefNameChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input  type="text" label="Last name" value={rec.LNAME} onchange={handlelnameChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input type="tel" label="Phone" value={rec.Phone} onchange={handlePhoneChange}></lightning-input><br/>
            <lightning-input  label="email" value={rec.EMAIL} onchange={handleEmailChange}></lightning-input><br/>
            <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
JAVASCRIPT CONTROLLER

import { LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';

import FNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.FirstName';
import LNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.LastName';
import PHONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Phone';
import EMAIL_FIELD  from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Email';
import insertContact from '@salesforce/apex/NewContactImperative.insertContact';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';



export default class LwcNewContactUsingApexImperativecalling extends LightningElement {

       @track fname=FNAME_FIELD;
       @track lname =LNAME_FIELD;
       @track Phone= PHONE_FIELD;
       @track email =EMAIL_FIELD;
        
        rec={
            FNAME:this.fname,
            LNAME:this.lname,
            Phone:this.Phone,
            EMAIL:this.email,
         }

    handlefNameChange(event) {
        this.rec.FNAME = event.target.value;
        window.console.log("FNAME", this.rec.FNAME);
        
    }
    
    handlelnameChange(event) {
        this.rec.LNAME = event.target.value;
        window.console.log("LNAME", this.rec.LNAME);
    }
    
    handlePhoneChange(event) {
        this.rec.Phone = event.target.value;
        window.console.log("Phone", this.rec.Phone);
    }

    handleEmailChange(event) {
        this.rec.EMAIL = event.target.value;
        window.console.log("EMAIL", this.rec.EMAIL);
    }

    handleClick() {
        insertContact ({ con : this.rec })
            .then(result => {
                this.message = result;
                this.error = undefined;
                if(this.message !== undefined) {
                    this.rec={};
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Success',
                            message: 'Account created',
                            variant: 'success',
                        }),
                    );
                }
                
                window.console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                window.console.log("result", this.message);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.message = undefined;
                this.error = error;
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error creating record',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error',
                    }),
                );
                window.console.log("error", JSON.stringify(this.error));

            });
    }
}
```

```
APEX CONTROLLER 

public with sharing class NewContactImperative {
 
    /*Using multiple parameter in apex  controller */

     @AuraEnabled
    public static void insertContact(Contact con){
        System.debug('acc--'+con);
        try{
            insert con;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you be precise here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apex method requires a `Contact` as input parameter, but you're passing an object with these four properties that are not Contact's fields:

- FNAME
- LNAME
- Phone
- EMAIL

You could either edit both JS and HTML files renaming them with the right names (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Phone` and `Email`) or change `insertContact ({ con : this.rec })` to

```js
const contact = {
    FirstName: this.rec.FNAME,
    LastName: this.rec.LNAME,
    Phone: this.rec.Phone,
    Email: this.rec.EMAIL
}
insertContact ({ con : contact })
```

**Beware** - the apex method returns `void`, so nothing, but you're handling a result here: `this.message = result;`, so it will always hold null. By the way, you never defined `message` nor `error` in your class, so there are no `this.message` and `this.error`.

If you need/want to display a message returned from apex, you should change the signature of the apex method.
If it could return void, because even if an exception is raised it will be handled by the `catch` of the promise, the `handleClick` method can be rewritten as follow:

```js
handleClick() {
    const contact = {
        FirstName: this.rec.FNAME,
        LastName: this.rec.LNAME,
        Phone: this.rec.Phone,
        Email: this.rec.EMAIL
    }
    insertContact ({ con : contact })
        .then(() => {
            // this.rec={}; // Don't. You aren't clearing the value of rec properties, you're removing them. So everywhere you're using them you'll get an error because they will be now undefined properties.
            this.rec.FNAME = null;
            this.rec.LNAME = null;
            this.rec.Phone = null;
            this.rec.EMAIL = null;
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Contact created',
                    variant: 'success',
                }),
            );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error creating record',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error',
                }),
            );
            console.log('error', JSON.stringify(error));
        });
}
```

Lastly you could remove `@track` decorator from your code, there is no property that requires it.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH @RubenDG.